# Can I download a specific Mass Effect game from The Mass Effect Trilogy?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-series

So, I want to buy Mass Effect Trilogy but I don't have that much space on my ps3. (I want to buy the game digital) So, can I download the games individual? or do I have to download the 33 gb with the 3 games?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bought the Mass Effect trilogy on PSN. It appears on my download list as three separate items that can be downloaded separately.

Answer (score 1):

[According to a post on Reddit, yes](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS3/comments/36603j/mass_effect_trilogy_physical_or_psn_download/crb2ffa). It's likely the size you are seeing is what the *combined size* of all three games is. [Here are the sizes from the same topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS3/comments/36603j/mass_effect_trilogy_physical_or_psn_download/crbbyxc).

In my opinion, I would be surprised the game does not have individual downloads, considering the DLC, games, etc., really rack up and much of the games are dissimilar save a few oddities. Of course, the alternative (what I have done) is buy the disc set or each game individually (higher price), so I cannot confirm that.